# No module named rest_authusers error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am in the process of adding allauth to my project, following this tutorial:
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

When trying to make migrations I get the following error:
"ImportError: No module named rest_authusers"

My settings.py is as follows:

```
   # Application definition
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_auth'
        'users',
        # The Django sites framework is required
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    )

    SITE_ID = 1

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Am furthermore not sure how to fix this as there is no reference of authusers in my project files.

Traceback: https://dpaste.de/2SDB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply forgot to put the comma after `'rest_auth'` ;)